# Ribbon in css3 that goes from side to side

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the results on this page http://www.andreapinchi.it/css3-ribbon/

The Side to side one of course but I can't seem to get the '3D' effect.

Please see

http://jsfiddle.net/vuvzcot6/

[html]

```
<div class="box">
<div class="ribbon both_ribbon">
    <h2>Ribbon side to side</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

[css]

```
div.both_ribbon{
    background: lime;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px 9px 10px 10px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

div.both_ribbon::before{
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: -11px;
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid rgb(0, 80, 116);
}

div.both_ribbon::after{
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid rgb(0, 80, 116);
}

.box { 
    width: 850px;
    height: 800px;
    background: #82caff;
}
```

Someone please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the `ribbon` CSS class, which is necessary for the other classes to work:

```
.ribbon{
    color: #fff;
    margin: 30px 0 50px;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: rgb(0, 164, 239);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    padding: 10px 15px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: If I wanted it to surround the whole page instead of the div, how would I do that?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean have a panel that looks like a ribbon hold all your content?

Comment: Like if instead of the div it was the whole page lengthwise. Do you get what I'm saying?

Comment: Or if the div was at 100% width

Comment: I think you would get your intended effect if you simply put more content in the `ribbon` div. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/r9ou9ak5/

Comment: what if I just wanted a the text to say welcome. That wouldn't work?